# How to implement Socket.PollAsync in C#

Tags: sockets, c#-4.0, async-await

Is it possible to implement the equivalent of Socket.Poll in async/await paradigm (or BeginXXX/EndXXX async pattern)?

A method which would act like NetworkStream.ReadAsync or Socket.BeginReceive but:

- leave the data in the socket buffer
- complete after the specified interval of time if no data arrived (leaving the socket in connected state so that the polling operation can be retried)

I need to implement IMAP IDLE so that the client connects to the mail server and then goes into waiting state where it received data from the server. If the server does not send anything within 10 minutes, the code sends ping to the server (without reconnecting, the connection is never closed), and starts waiting for data again.

In my tests, leaving the data in the buffer seems to be possible if I tell Socket.BeginReceive method to read no more than 0 bytes, e.g.:

```
sock.BeginReceive(b, 0, 0, SocketFlags.None, null, null)
```

However, not sure if it indeed will work in all cases, maybe I'm missing something. For instance, if the remote server closes the connection, it may send a zero-byte packet and not sure if Socket.BeginReceive will act identically to Socket.Poll in this case or not.

And the main problem is how to stop socket.BeginReceive without closing the socket.

Comment: If you are willing to relax one condition ("leave the data in the socket buffer") standard async/await techniques would apply. This suggests you could achieve what you want simply by including code to buffer any data that *is* received by the "polling" operation. Closing the socket to cancel asynchronous I/O is then only necessary if you're done using the socket altogether.

Comment: Why can't you just always read from the stream whatever is coming. That is the standard way of doing things.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Indeed, buffering the data I received can workaround polling but I don't get how this solves my main problem - to stop reading operation so that I would be able to send more data to socket. Or, is it possible to send something (do BeginSend) while the previous BeginReceive is still in progress?

Comment: @usr This assumes the data will come eventually. However, in case of push notifications (like IMAP IDLE) it's not so. The client may stop receiving data at any moment, send a command to the server to stop IDLE mode and continue other operations. Without closing the connection. This is no problem with sync I/O but async data receive seems to last forever until data is received (and the way option to stop it is to close the socket which is not an option for me).

Comment: Yes. In fact, this is the common pattern for async socket I/O: you have one `BeginReceive` pump that takes care of incoming data and you issue `BeginSend` whenever you have something to send. Shutting down the socket (or receiving 0 bytes) ends the receive "loop". Multiple asynchronous operations may be pending on a socket.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Oh, looks like I can leave data in Socket's internal buffer without implementing my own buffering (which is possible but would take some time) simply by using SocketFlags.Peek in BeginReceive. Just wondering how I overlook this obvious solution before..

Comment: One good reason to overlook it is that [Microsoft recommends against its use](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192599/). You *might* get it to work in your scenario, but even so, it's not a best practice.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, I'm aware of that and thus I'm using Peek carefully. It's indeed bad idea to use it to accumulate data between multiple read operations (such as to wait until the entire data structure is received or something like that). But in my case I mostly read zero-length packets with it (to check when the server closes the connection - this causes zero-length packet to appear) and when it comes to reading real data blocks I always use normal Receive. Anyway, when time permits, I'll get rid of any Peek at all.